# What is the best way to serve static web pages from within a Django application?

Tags: python, django, static, templates

I am building a relatively simple [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) application and apart from the main page where most of the dynamic parts of the application are, there are a few pages that I will need that will not be dynamic at all (*About*, *FAQ*, etc.). What is the best way to integrate these into Django, idealing still using the Django template engine? Should I just create a template for each and then have a view that simply renders that template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked at [flat pages](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/#ref-contrib-flatpages) in Django?  It probably does everything you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to just create a template for each of them, you could use the [`direct_to_template`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template) generic view to serve it up.

Another option would be the [`django.contrib.flatpages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/flatpages/) app, which would let you configure the static URLs and content via the database.