# looking for a Python based web-app to serve files

Tags: python, web-applications, web, passenger, wsgi

I am looking for a Python-based alternatives for [AutoIndex PHP Script](http://autoindex.sourceforge.net/). Preferably it runs under [WSGI](http://www.wsgi.org/).

The features of AutoIndex are listed [here](http://autoindex.sourceforge.net/index.php?id=features) and there is also a [live demo](http://autoindex.sourceforge.net/demo/).

Note:
+ I'm not looking for a [web](http://twistedmatrix.com/) [server](http://www.tornadoweb.org/). My shared web hosting doesn't allow me to run my own background process.
+ Neither am I looking for [web](http://pylonshq.com/) [frameworks](http://www.djangoproject.com/) (I am OK with using frameworks, it's just that I'm looking for a ready to use web-app instead of writing my own web-app on top of frameworks. if there is none, maybe i should write my own.)

Comment: Are you looking for a framework to serve flat files?  What are the important features of AutoIndex?

Comment: python -c "import SimpleHTTPServer;SimpleHTTPServer.test()"

Comment: @The MYYN: Please post your answer as an answer, so we can upvote it properly.

Comment: If you're serving files, what's wrong with Apache?  You can't add a background process and you don't want a Python framework.  There's not much left.

Comment: uhm, actually I'm OK using Python frameworks, it's just that I'm looking for a ready to use web-app instead of writing on my own web-app on top of frameworks. But maybe I should write my own if there's none.

Comment: @afriza: Please update your question to actually state your actual requirements all in one place.  It's impossible to piece your requirements together from the thread comments.

Comment: @10661: I think the requirement is clear. I want something similar to AutoIndex PHP Script. If you are not familiar with it, you can try the online demo and or try it out in your favorite web-server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Flask-Autoindex is what you're looking for...](http://packages.python.org/Flask-AutoIndex/)

> Flask-AutoIndex generates an index page for your Flask application automatically. The result just like mod_autoindex, but the look is more awesome! Look at this:

[image: flask]

Comment: This is the closest that I see. Although it doesn't seem to have all features of PHP-AutoIndex.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this question:

[What is the best way to serve static web pages from within a Django application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252035/what-is-the-best-way-to-serve-static-web-pages-from-within-a-django-app)

Use Django with the flatpages app.  I cannot be sure, since your comments and your question disagree, but I think this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Pylons and Django are two popular frameworks for Python that use templates, models, pretty url's etc.. They are both open source.

Pylons: http://pylonshq.com/

Django: http://www.djangoproject.com/

They both should do everything you need.